# C type converted from char* to int when passing to function

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass a file name to a threaded function but it's type is converted to int inside the function

```
struct Data {
    char file_name;
}
void *Requestor(void *args) {
    struct Data *data = (struct Data*)args;
    printf("%s\n", data->file_name); //says expected char* but argument is type of int
}

int file_count = 5;
struct Data files[file_count];

for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[5 + i]); //this prints the file_name correctly;
    files[i].file_name = argv[5 + i]; // I get: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion when compiling
    int thread = pthread_create(&(requesterThreads[i]), NULL, Requestor, &files[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `*`: `char file_name;` should be `char *file_name;` The reason the compiler warns you that it's an `int` instead of a `char` is that `char` is implicitly promoted to `int` when used in varargs.